# How to extract the loss function of a trained model?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, pytorch, tensorflow2.0

Lets say that I have a model trained with TF2 (e.g., a model from TF model zoo). How can I get the loss function of this model?

Note that I do not want the value of the loss for a given input (that can be obtained via model.evaluate method), but I want the loss function itself such that:

- I can take its gradient with respect to input or any desired parameter
- I can pass the labels and logits and it provide me the loss value
- Note that I am using an already trained model (inheriting tf.keras.Model).

Comment: I don't think this is possible.

Comment: For Tensorflow: It is possible, but this depends on how the model was saved. I suggest reading the [Keras guide](https://keras.io/guides/serialization_and_saving/) for information on the different formats. Since the loss function is usually passed in `compile`, it can only be restored from the saved model if that model was compiled in the first place, and the compile information was saved. The model object should have attributes such as `losses` and `compiled_loss` which you can check for content.